# Reference field within same schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to reference field within same schema? See my example below. Or am I going about this wrong way?

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    foods: [{
      name: String,
      category: String,
      ingredients: // how to reference values in the ingredients array?
    }], 
    ingredients: [{
      name: String,
      category: String
    }]  
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**

This is a core MongoDB design decision:  [MongoDB relationships: embed or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373198/mongodb-relationships-embed-or-reference)

Storing references to objects, rather than independent copies of them, as you would do in a relational database is possible in MongoDB and often done, it just results in more and more complex queries when you need to look them up.

**Long answer**

If the goal is just to keep the definitions of ingredient schemas consistent, you can define a schema and use it twice.  The ingredients will be stored as independent copies, e.g.

```
[{  username: 'bob', 
    ingredients: [  { name: 'Carrot', category: 'Vegetable' } , ...],
    foods:  [ { name: 'Salad', category: 'Lunch', ingredients: [ { name: 'Carrot', category: 'Vegetable'}, ...]}]
}, ...]


var IngredientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  category: String,
});


var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    foods: [{
      name: String,
      category: String,
      ingredients: [IngredientSchema] // brackets indicates it's an array, 
    }], 
    ingredients: [IngredientSchema]  
});
```

Alternatively you can reference ingredients by objectId:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
     username: String,
     password: String,
    email: String,
    foods: [{
      name: String,
      category: String,
      ingredients: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId] // IDs reference individual ingredients, 
    }], 
    ingredients: [IngredientSchema]  
});
```

By defining IngredientSchema explicitly, each ingredient object gets its own ObjectId when it is declared.   The upside to storing IDs of ingredients (rather than copies of ingredient objects) is more concise and consistent storage.  The downside is there will be many more and more complex queries.

```
[{  username: 'bob', 
    ingredients: [  { _id: ObjectId('a298d9ef898afc98ddf'), name: 'Carrot', category: 'Vegetable' } , ...],
    foods:  [ { name: 'Salad', category: 'Lunch', ingredients: [ {$oid: 'a298d9ef898afc98ddf'}, ]}]
}, ...]
```

A better approach if you want to store references to Ingredients, may be to store Ingredients as its own first class collection.  You'll still have many separate queries when you want to look up foods by ingredient, or ingredients by food, but the queries will be simpler.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
     username: String,
     password: String,
     email: String,
     foods: [{
      name: String,
      category: String,
      ingredients: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId] // IDs reference individual ingredients, 
    }], 
    ingredients: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]  
});
```

if the goal is store normalized references to ingredients and search foods based on them, to quote another [SO post][1], "this is one of those cases where relational databases really shine"

See this SO post for querying subdocuments by Id:
[Reading categories and number of articles in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706817/mongodb-reading-categories-and-number-of-articles-in-a-single-query)

As one respondent notes, "this is one of those cases where relational databases really shine"

Comment: Does it mean I must create two schemas if I want to use reference instead of embedding? My initial idea was to keep ingredients field under user schema because each user can define their own set of ingredients. Now with new IngredientSchema I would be storing ingredients from all users under one schema (collection). That's not really what I need. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Also, trying to understand why did you suggest to reference IngredientSchema from both foods.ingredients field and ingredients field. Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: In the example I gave there's only one Schema for Ingredients, but the ingredient objects are stored verbatim independently within each food, as copies not references.  But I see you want to refer to ingredients by an ID not as duplicates.  Will edit answer above...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updated answer, it shed some light into my problem. The reason why I'm looking to reference ingredients instead of storing copies is that I want user to be able to easily update ingredient (e.g. user realizes there is a typo in an ingredient and wants to correct it). Updating multiple copies of each ingredient might be too complicated. Unless there is some magical MongoDB operator, which I haven't yet discovered, which can easily update every occurrence of a string in whole document :)

Comment: I have a similar situation and like MongoDB for many reasons. I recommend keeping Ingredients as a first class collection, and storing the _id attribute in the ingredients arrays.    If later you need to find users or foods with a specific ingredient, use the $in query operator.